# playing mp3 and difference between file:/// and http://

Tags: html, media

i have a problem about playing mp3/mp4 in firefox and internet explorer, what difference between run a page including following code using double-click on it(file:///...) and run that using iis (http ://...)

```
<object data="../../Media/Music.mp3" width="200" height="150" type="audio/mpeg"></object>
```

when i double click on it file music or movie doesn't play, but when i open it using iis (http ://) music plays???
what's the difference? thanks all

Comment: `file:///` referts to something on the actual machine and `http ://` on the web ... it's not two different protocols to access the same ressource

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely running into Same Origin Policy problem regarding file: URIs.

See [this MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs):

> For example, if you have a file foo.html which accesses another file bar.html and you have navigated to it from the file index.html, the load will succeed only if bar.html is either in the same directory as index.html or in a directory contained within the same directory as index.html.

Try moving your mp3 to a directory that is contained within the same directory as your HTML-file.

Comment: This doesn't apply to media

Comment: @Pete TNT : i've done as you said and moved music.mp3 to same directory containing my html file, in Internet Explorer problem was solved but in Firefox wasn't... what should i do to play mp3 in Firefox?